# Problems resolving host alias

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure my nginx-rtmp module.
In my `/etc/host.aliases` I have

```
web   mysite.com
```

`ping web` doing just fine.

In my nginx-rtmp conf I have

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            on_play http://web/api/events/play;
        }
    }
}
```

and with this config it fails to load:
`host not found in url "web/api/events/play"`

How could that be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/host.aliases` is not used by every path for resolving addresses from names, and [it only works when the `HOSTALIASES` environment variable is set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104511/5906), anyway.  So nginx is either not using the "blessed methods" for doing name resolution, and/or the environment isn't set correctly for `/etc/host.aliases` to be consulted.

Comment: I've tried to google, but did not find any posts or questions that showing problems with HOSTALIASES and nginx. I found almost nothing, so I can't say whether it uses "blessed methods" or not. Any ideas how to know this? I always can open an issue on github, but that's not the best thing ever =)

Comment: Read The Source, Luke.  (or `ltrace` output).  You could also try injecting the environment variable first, and see if that fixes it.